# Mysql Replication : The table does not comply with the requirements by an external plugin

Tags: mysql, symfony, replication

I have a Symfony project in a MySQL Master-Master replication.
When I try to INSERT an user in database, I got this error :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3098 The table does not comply with the requirements by an external plugin.
```

When I try to INSERT a data in an other table, no problem.

MySQL version : 8.0.13

I checked requirements for replication : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-replication-requirements.html

InnoDB Storage Engine : OK

Primary Keys : OK

Network Performance : OK

I also tried to disable strict mode but no success.

Is there something special to do with MySQL 8.x version ?

Thank you per advance.

Comment: Do you mean a mysql user (e.g. you are trying to manually insert something into `mysql.user`) or your own table that manages your users?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I try to add an user in a table that manage my users, not in mysql.user.

Comment: I think you can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75927040/14173036).