# Error Importing data to MySQL Group Replication

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-group-replication

I'm taking a backup from a standalone database using the following command:

```
mysqldump -u <user> -p --databases <some databases> --no-create-info --no-create-db --skip-triggers --single-transaction --compress --order-by-primary > data.sql
```

When I'm importing the data into a MySQL Group Replication, I get this error:

> ERROR 3098 (HY000) at line 2150: The table does not comply with the requirements by an xternal plugin.

The last line that the restore ran was: `alter table disable keys` and the error stopped appearing when the `alter table enable keys`.

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268697/error-3098-hy000-the-table-does-not-comply-with-the-requirements-by-an-extern

Comment: Thanks, but I managed to figure it out.
One of the MySQL GroupReplication is a Primary Key for each table. All of these errors were on the same table that had no Primary Key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to figure it out.
One of the MySQL GroupReplication requirements is to have a Primary Key for each table. Unlike `Standalone` Mysql that doesn't require it.
I took the data from a Standalone Mysql and tried to import it into a Group Replication.
As I find out, only 1 table didn't have a `Primary Key` so the import always failed on that table with that error.